# Hide a view in the view menu

Tags: 2007, web-part, list-view, hidden

I have created a view in a custom list, with audience targeting option on the web part (the list), to only allow specific users to access the view.

Is it possible to hide the view name in the view menu (the drop-down view menu on the top right corner)?

More precisely, I would like to hide the view in the view menu to the users who don't have access to this view. I don't want them being able to know the existence of this view.

I'm using MOSS with Owners rights.